# Post photo to someone else's wall or album from mobile device

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Here's the functionality I want. I want users of my mobile apps (iOS, Android) to be able to post photos from their device to a facebook page of someone else. This facebook page is not owned by the user of my app, nor is the user a friend or fan. Also, the facebook page may be a standard page, or an event page or a fan page, depending on the client.

Any solution will work. For example, it may be that I will have to make the app upload all photos to a server owned by me, then from that central server I could use the facebook api to post the photo to a client's facebook page. I could make a sort of go between facebook account and that account could be friends with the client's facebook or be a page admin, etc.  Or maybe the client will provide me with their facebook credentials and I could post it as them.

Ideally I want to do this all from the app and not have a go between, but whatever works.

How can I make this happen?

---

I'm just going to go ahead and say this is not possible. It would be very cool, but not possible. Here's the functionality I wanted. A user goes to a big music festival. The festival has its own app that I developed. Inside the festival's app the user can take a pic and press a button and the pic would be uploaded to the festival's facebook page, not the user's. So the festival's facebook page would get fan photos posted to it straight from the user. The only way I see this as working is by having the app upload all pics to a sort of go between server then have that server post the pic to the festival's facebook page by using the festival's login credentials. This would require the festival to give me, the developer, their login credentials, which they may be reluctant to do.

If anyone knows how I can do this straight from the app please let me know.

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually have a problem, but rather asking for someone to come up with a solution for you. Have you taken a look at the facebook graph api to see how you could use it to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the api. The problem is, the api is very ambiguous in some places and doesn't clearly say if this functionality is even possible. I spent half a day searching and reading forums and people have been asking these questions but no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Myself am busy with the same thing. Did research for two full days and did not find the answer for our problem. But i think i have an explanation for it.

if a user posts a photo to friend/fan_page with the official android FB app it uses a "feed" with a picture(url-link). The user can't see on his own wall that he actually shared or posted a picture on the friend/fan_page. (for example: "Bob - posted a photo on CocaCola")

This is probably the reason why the function is disabled because developers could use this to send photo's to all kinds of pages/people without the user knowing be aware of it.

I came to this hypotheses because i found a sort of work around. Upload photo to users own album. get the URL of that photo and then post a "feed" with a picture(url-lnk). Facebook then gave this error: "FBCDN image is not allowed in stream" in other words, you can't use photos that are on FB website domain to link to. So think there is quite a bug/lazyness in the facebook developement departmet :P